# "ValueError: negative count return bytes(bytearray(seq))" on raspberry pi

Tags: python, arduino

I wanna send a negative string from a raspberry pi to an arduino and got this error on the raspis cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 363, in <module>
    ser.write(LinePosLastLoop[6])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 532, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 66, in to_bytes
    return bytes(bytearray(seq))
ValueError: negative count
```

Program:

```
value = str(linePos).encode()

value = int(float(value))

LinePosLastLoop[6] = value

ser.write(LinePosLastLoop[6])
```

I tried to shorten my program as much as possible to make it easier to understand, but if I miss something or anything is unclear, please comment that and I will all the information you need.
Thanks for possible answers

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that

```
LinePosLastLoop[6]
```

is a string which have to be converted to a byte before sending via uart. So to fix this error just change

```
ser.write(LinePosLastLoop[6])
```

to

```
ser.write(str(LinePosLastLoop[6]/10).encode())
```

I hope I could help any futher readers!